# CircuitLab Broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I mean, it's slow at inserting a schematic at the best of times - but for me the schematic editor just won't work today. It just sits there spinning its wheels when you try to insert the schematic into a question or answer.

Is anyone else able to insert a schematic today, or is it just me?

Comment: Looks like it's working now :)

Comment: Indeed. I just used it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the network logs in [KingDuken's answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7012/is-there-a-problem-with-circuitlab-save-and-insert-today/7013#7013) over on EE, it appears that CircuitLab's server was having some issues and providing a response that the front-end didn't know how to handle.

It appears to be working now. Hopefully it stays that way...

Answer (score 0):

It's broken for me. I did get a "Your browser is not officially supported..." message before I could use CircuitLab to draw a circuit. Clicking the button to insert it into the answer just turned the "spinning wait graphic" on.

Comment: I don't get a message - just the spinner.